# I cannot open the menu editor (menulibre)

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, python3, menulibre

I cannot open the *Menu Editor* in Xubuntu 18.04. either via the *Settings Manager* (as shown in the picture) or via terminal (command `menulibre`)

[image]

When I execute `menulibre` in the terminal i get following error message:

```
ping: f6903536d567a64584e4a6331526f5a5652796458526f4f327077595474745a.sub.deliverycontent.online: Name or service not known                                                                                                                  
ping: 690157353162476c69636d56664d6934794c6a45374c32687662575576616e.sub.deliverycontent.online: Name or service not known                                                                                                                   
ping: 690242684c79356a59574e6f5a513d3d.sub.deliverycontent.online: Name or service not known                                                                                                                                                 
/home/jpa/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/__init__.py:104: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.12) or chardet (5.0.0)/charset_normalizer (3.0.0) doesn't match a supported version!                                         
  RequestsDependencyWarning)                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  File "/usr/bin/menulibre", line 45, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                                            
    menulibre.main()                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
AttributeError: module 'menulibre' has no attribute 'main'
```

I have reinstalled `menulibre` through the package manager but the error persists.

How can I run the *Menu Editor* again?

Answer (score 0):

As a make-shift solution I found the `alacarte` menu editing tool, which is in the standard distro repository.

I could expediently install it with the `Synaptic Package Manager` or, alternatively, run following in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install alacarte
```

It is not so full featured as `menulibre`, but, at least I can edit the Menu at GUI. :)

[image]